# Como plotar um gráfico ao encerrar um script de visão computacional no Raspberry pi?

Tags: python, matplotlib, opencv, raspberry-pi

Eu tenho um código usando opencv Raspberry Pi e ele está executando um reconhecimento de padrões de loop. No final encerro o script usando "Ctrl + X" sem nenhum problema! Eu quero ao mandar "parar" o processamento gráfico, executar uma função para traçar um gráfico das informações de reconhecimento, como posição, tamanho e outros parâmetros.

Como posso fazer isso?

No código de exemplo eu coloquei a chamada de função quando parar .. mas não obtive sucesso. Nome da função é "Relatorio_Movimentos

```
while True:

// outras funções de reconhecimento, loop do processamento

if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
 break
Relatorio_Movimentos(Parado, Aj_Sup, Aj_Inf, Dir, Esq, Frt, Trs)
cv.DestroyAllWindows()  
gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: Tente adicionar um cv::waitKey(0); depois da função que gera o relatório e antes de destruir as janelas. Talvez o relatório esteja executando certinho mas o programa encerra antes que você possa ver o resultado...

Comment: Crie o Relatorio_Movimentos em uma thread. E mantenha a aplicação original esperando pelo ponto de parada. Se acontecer, mate a thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Se o usuário pressionar a tecla ESC
if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
    // Exibir o relatório
    Relatorio_Movimentos(Parado, Aj_Sup, Aj_Inf, Dir, Esq, Frt, Trs)

    // Observe que se a função acima exibir uma janela do OpenCV, você deve invocar:
    //cv.WaitKey(0)
    break
```